# Python multi processing on for loop

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a function with two parameters

```
reqs =[1223,1456,1243,20455]
url = "pass a url"
def crawl(i,url):
   print("%s is %s" % (i, url))
```

I want to trigger above function by multi processing concept.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)   
    print(p.map([crawl(i,url) for i in reqs]))
```

above code is not working for me. can anyone please help me on this!

----- ADDING NEW CODE ---------

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

reqs = [1223,1456,1243,20455]
url = "pass a url"

def crawl(combined_args):
   print("%s is %s" % (combined_args[0], combined_args[1]))

def main():
    p = Pool(5)   
    print(p.map(crawl, [(i,url) for i in reqs]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I am trying to execute above code, I am getting below error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. crawl function should in separate module like below:

**crawler.py**

```
def crawl(combined_args):
   print("%s is %s" % (combined_args[0], combined_args[1]))
```

**run.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import crawler

def main():
    p = Pool(5)   
    print(p.map(crawler.crawl, [(i,url) for i in reqs]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then output will be like below:

```
**output :**

1223 is pass a url
1456 is pass a url
1243 is pass a url
20455 is pass a url
[None, None, None, None]  # This is the output of the map function
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [multiprocessing.Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) this is the function argument line:

```
map(func, iterable[, chunksize])
```

You are trying to pass to the map a iterator instead of `(func, iterable)`.

Please refer to the following example of multiprocessing.pool ([source](https://www.journaldev.com/15631/python-multiprocessing-example)):

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

work = (["A", 5], ["B", 2], ["C", 1], ["D", 3])

def work_log(work_data):
    print(" Process %s waiting %s seconds" % (work_data[0], work_data[1]))
    time.sleep(int(work_data[1]))
    print(" Process %s Finished." % work_data[0])

def pool_handler():
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(work_log, work)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_handler()
```

Please note that he is passing one argument to the `work_log` function and in the function he use the index to get to the relevant fields.

---

Refering to your example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

reqs = [1223,1456,1243,20455]
url = "pass a url"

def crawl(combined_args):
   print("%s is %s" % (combined_args[0], combined_args[1]))

def main():
    p = Pool(5)   
    print(p.map(crawl, [(i,url) for i in reqs]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results with:

```
1223 is pass a url
1456 is pass a url
1243 is pass a url
20455 is pass a url
[None, None, None, None]  # This is the output of the map function
```

Comment: okay. but  when I am trying to execute above code, facing some issue.  I have edited my question, also I have added error screenshot.